# Delete isolated entity from DB

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I don't believe the following exists but thought it was worth the ask.

Say I have an entity `Contact` with the following property:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Address> addresses;
```

Assuming an `Address` is unique so it cannot belong to any other `Contact`. I can obviously use **cascade** so that operations performed on `Contact` are cascaded to `Address` but is there an annotation to remove an `Address` from the DB if it is removed from `List<Address> addresses`.

EG. A `Contact` `List<Address> addresses` property contains 3 `Address` values; `Address#1`, `Address#2` and `Address#3`.

`Address#3` is removed and `Contact` is merged back to the DB using the entity manager. At this point `Address#3` still exists in the DB but is no longer associated with anything. I have always manually dealt with this but it strikes me that its a relatively common occurrence (for me at least) and there might be an annotation that takes care of this.

Comment: Are you looking for [orphan removal](http://nsinfra.blogspot.de/2013/03/jpa-20-hibernate-orphanremoval-true.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [orphan removal option](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/):

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, , orphanRemoval="true")
private List<Address> addresses;
```

This will cause addresses to be deleted when you remove them from your list.